# query regarding using external table concept in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, external-tables

While using external table one BAD file was generated.
 `BAD file(“abc.bad”)` has data like

```
“E51″,12345,555333,”anbd”,”kksksk”  
E51″,12345233,55333,”anbd”,”kksksk”
```

How can I insert above data into table in a single column as varchar.
currently the default field separator defined in oracle is `,` and it's inserting only the 1st field.

How to override this default definition to consider entire record and insert into a single column

Comment: You could insert the file in a column as blob or clob

Comment: @Typo . how can i read clob column  and insert into a table

Comment: Check this: http://geekswithblogs.net/robertphyatt/archive/2010/03/24/write-read-and-update-oracle-clobs-with-plsql.aspx